# Extracting date from datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a value from my database.
How do I extract the date from this datetime value using javascript?

```
1990-06-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075893/114801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just split up the parts and use the built-in `Date` constructor

```
var t = "1990-06-03 00:00:00".split(/[- :]/);
var date = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
```