# jQuery validate:date - mysql format

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-validate

How can i change jQuery validate 'date' to mysql format? 
With the current one, my MySql dates are not valid.

MySQL date format - `YYYY-MM-DD`

Also, is there a native 'time' validator? Or do you have to add your own method for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql can generate ISO date .. if you "use strict" you should be able to use Date.parse in the future but for now check this : https://github.com/csnover/js-iso8601 and use the function for ISO date parsing.
For generating ISO from javascript date object check this question : [How do I output an ISO 8601 formatted string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript)

Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry , perhaps I have been hasty in my answer of the question although you have to use DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%dT%TZ') to get ISO date and it's probably easier to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format ignoring the second part of regexp

Comment: Why is this accepted answer? Is it possible to change format of date in JQuery validate ?