# how to format mysql timestamp into mm/dd/yyyy H:i:s in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am getting values from database which is a time stamp.And i need to convert it into mm/dd/yyyy H:i:s using javascript. i tried the following code. but its not working it firefox/ie.But its working in chrome..how to solve it.

```
function formatDate(value){
if(value){
    Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
        var  len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
        return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
    }
var d = new Date(value),
dformat = [ (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
            d.getDate().padLeft(),
            d.getFullYear()].join('/')+
           ' ' +
          [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
            d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
            d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
 return dformat;
}
```

I am getting NaN/NaN/NaN/NaN/NaN/NaN in firefox and ie.Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Here's a very short and compact way to format a MySQL date http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075893/2047369

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is missing a trailing `}`. If you formatted it better, you would see this:

```
function formatDate(value){
  if(value){
    Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){
      var len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1;
      return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this;
    }
    var d = new Date(value),
    dformat = [ (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft(),
                 d.getDate().padLeft(),
                 d.getFullYear()].join('/')+
              ' ' +
              [ d.getHours().padLeft(),
                d.getMinutes().padLeft(),
                d.getSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
    return dformat;
  }
}
```

It works fine in Firefox, now.

Note that you are defining `Number.prototype.padLeft` each time you call this function. It would be better to move this out of the function body.

---

**EDIT** As per my comment, the reason this is failing for you is that the `Date` object will only accept strings in certain formats. Moreover, it occurs to me that your function is just changing the format of a string: You don't really need to bother messing about with dates and, instead, just do string operations on your input:

```
var formatDate = function(dateString) {
  // Convert 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' to 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
  return dateString.replace(/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, '$2/$3/$1');
};
```

Much easier!

Comment: The problem is, if your timestamp is `2013-03-14 06:32:33`, that Firefox can't parse this: It will only parse [IETF-compliant RFC2822 timestamps](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14). A quick fix is to change the dashes to slashes: `var d = new Date(value.replace(/-/g, '/')),`, assuming the value parsed to the function will always be in the same format.

Comment: See edit for a more succinct solution, rather than messing with date parsing.

Answer (score 1):

```
function formatDate(d) 
{
    d = new Date(d * 1000);
    return d.getMonth() + 1 + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript already know how to work with a timestamp.

```
var d = new Date(timestamp * 1000); //will create a date object
```

You then can use all the Javascript Date methods to format it. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

EDIT : Convert timestamp to milliseconds (*1000)

Comment: @Deepu Show your timestamp value??

Comment: 2013-03-14 06:32:33 thats a time stamp value

Comment: @Deepu Is your database column really of type 'timestamp' ? Because a timestamp must look like this: 1363779021

Comment: You have to convert it to timestamp. You could use UNIX_TIMESTAMP() mysql function `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');`