# Parsing DateTime string fails in Firefox And Internet Explorer, works on Chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a datetime string that makes its way from an SQL database to my Javascript function.

```
2013-12-31 09:09:49
```

Chrome seems to parse it with no issue, but NaN is returned for Firefox and IE.

Why is this happening?

If it makes a difference, I'm using SQLServer 2012.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert MySql DateTime stamp into JavaScript's Date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way SQL creates datestrings (such as with `getdate()`) seems to differ from the way javascript handles datetime strings.

The Mozilla Devlopment networks [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) that datetime strings can be in [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).

This format is listed as being `2011-10-10T14:48:00` whereas your SQL string looks like `2011-10-10 14:48:00`.

All that needs to be done to make it a JS valid Datetime string is to replace the space with a T.

One way of doing this would be

```
var dateTime = "2013-12-31 09:09:49";
var jsValidDateTime = dateTime.split(" ").join("T");
Date.parse(jsValidDateTime); //output: 1388498989000
```

This information is valid as of Firefox 26 and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: This works for EcmaScript 5, so older browsers may not support this.