# Getting time between dates

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'm trying to write a countdown and it should expires on a `MySQL` **datetime** value.

Using `JavaScript` I can get today's time using `new Date()).getTime()` but then how can I get the time difference from JS date and the MySQL datetime, assuming MySQL datetime value is in the future

Comment: is this what you are looking for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787939/check-time-difference-in-javascript.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to pass the MySQL datetime to javascript and parse it as a javascript date, then just subtract one from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTime()` gives you the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

[Convert the MySQL datetime object to JS format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format), and then you can subtract the milliseconds and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as this:

```
new Date('2014-08-01 00:00:00').getTime()-new Date().getTime()
```

returned value:

```
7006311072//Js time timestamp
```