# datetime from db isnt being parse by javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, time

I have a datetime coming from the database that looks like: **2014-10-09 14:14:27**

I am pulling it with angular and trying to format it in a way that I can work with.  This is what I currently have:

```
$http.get('/ajax/get-feedings.php')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.listing = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      $scope.listing.push({
        date: new Date(data[i].date),
        feeding: data[i].feeding
      });
    }
  })
```

But javascript is saying that the date is invalid?  I have no idea what is going on.

This is the json that is coming in if that helps

```
[  
   {  
      "date":"2014-10-09 14:14:27",
      "feeding":[  
         {  
            "id":"13",
            "amount":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Try with `date: new Date(data[i].date.replace(' ', 'T'))`

Comment: I think this has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format

Comment: it is working for me in chrome : http://plnkr.co/edit/M2XuQmhgSgXPL60Ysy03?p=preview

Comment: So parse it yourself, use http://momentjs.com/

Comment: MomentJS is the way to go