# Get Javascript date & time using MySQL Date format and Timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I'm trying to form a Javascript date that looks like "2015-12-31 07:12:49", and is using Vancouver time.

I've gone through these forums and tried a million different functions but can't successfully build the date.

I tried following this article, but it doesn't show how to format the date to MYSQL datetime. [How to get Time of specific timezone using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207655/how-to-get-time-of-specific-timezone-using-javascript)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just get the dateTime, and the parse it and rebuild it?

Comment: @Jacques, forgot to mention I'm a PHP guy and not Javascript... sorry! Can you send me an example of what you mean?

Comment: This is how I got the datetime: (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 19).replace('T', ' ') -- not sure what timezone that is though, and if it's different for every browser.

Comment: Do you already have the date, or are you generating one?

Comment: @Jacques this is how I'm generating it: (new Date()).toISOString().substring(0, 19).replace('T', ' '). Wrong timezone though...

Comment: How would you do it in PHP? How about doing it in PHP and then grab it via ajax?

Comment: @jValdron I went through that post and tried it out, but I just can't figure out how to format it like MySQL datetime.

Comment: @steeped Personally I've stopped using native JS for times, I've always used moment.js (http://momentjs.com/). They have a neat library to parse and convert date/time to all kinds of formats. If you know your date/time will always be -8, you could just create a date object from your timetsamp like so (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format) and then do * -8 hours.

Comment: The answer I marked as duplicate explains why you cannot do what you are asking.  Specifically, the `Date` object itself does not have a format, nor can it be put into any particular time zone.  You can craft a string using moment.js (or manually), and if you need to convert to a particular time zone first, then you can use moment-timezone or one of the other options mentioned in the duplicate.