# Returning SQL timestamp and converting it in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, sql, time, timestamp

A quick question on how i pass a timestamp from SQL trough PHP into JavaScript and then convert it into a unix timestamp.

The goal here is so retrieve a timestamp from my DB to which i add X hours and set is as endtime for my clock.

JavaScript

```
var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

PHP (time.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT max(time), time FROM user'";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
echo date($row['time']);}
```

I get the time using

```
$('#sqltime').load('time.php');
```

But i am absolutely not sure how to

Comment: Possible duplicate??  Although it's not EXACTLY the same as it is but essentially your just asking to convert a mysql timestamp to a javascript date object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format