# Convert datetime mysql to date JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I'd like to know how to convert datetime mysql to date in JavaScript. I want to calculate a gap between 2 dates in seconds (get the gap number of seconds between 2 dates).

Comment: would you atleast share expected output ?

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075577/convert-mysql-datetime-stamp-into-javascripts-date-format) is what you are looking for

Comment: It's kinda what I want yes

Comment: On the first day, just start counting slowly in your head, until the target day arrives

Answer (score -1):

Please try following code:

```js
let date1 = new Date("2017-12-21");
let date2 = new Date("2017-12-31");

let diffInSeconds = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime())/1000;
console.log(diffInSeconds);

let date3 = new Date("2018-01-12 01:00:31");
let date4 = new Date("2018-01-12 02:30:32");

diffInSeconds = (date4.getTime() - date3.getTime())/1000;

console.log(diffInSeconds);
```

Hope it helps :)